# Declare multiple variables of the same type java

Tags: java

I've read that we can declare multiple variables in one line like:

```
int one, two, three;
```

My question is that what if I want to declare a large number of variables of the same type, for example, the number of variables can go up to 20?

For instance, how do I assign each square on the chessboard to a variable? Thanks in advance

Comment: use an array would be better `int square [64];`

Comment: using array ... study java arrays

Comment: You can do this by using Array or ArrayList<Integer> . Array: Simple fixed sized data type. ArrayList is  Dynamic sized

Answer (score 2):

In your case you should use a 2 dimensional arrays instead like this:

```
Figurine[][] board = new Figurine[8][8];
```

where `Figurine` denotes the type you invent to track the chess-figures on the board.

**Edit**

Due to the extended conversation in the comment section here some advices / suggestions how to design a *Chessboard*:

```
public class ChessBoard {
    private final BoardSquare[][] squares = new BoardSquare[8][8];

    ...
}
```

This way you would hide the internal structure of your *Chessboard* from the rest of your program. Just provide methods to `add`, `move` and `remove` figurines from  the *Chessboard* following the rules of *Chess*.

Comment: Cool, just one more question, in case the type is not `int` anymore. For example, I create an interface call `ChessboardSquare` (and then a class implements that interface) and I want to declare multiple objects of the interface in another class. Would it still be good to use this method to declare variables?

Comment: Sure it would. I selected `Figurine` but you may replace it with `ChessboardSquare`. But a even better solution would be to define a new type `ChessBoard` having a field varaible `ChessboardSquare[8][8] squares;` hiding the internal structure / implementation from the rest of your program.

Answer (score 0):

You should opt for an `array` or `ArrayList` for handling large variables scenarios.

`int[] array = new int[20];`
`List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` or `Array` can be a suitable choice for you . Study about `java array` . Here is an example for you .

```
int[] simple=new int[100];
List<Integer> simpleList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Multi-dimensional array is most appropriate .

```
int[][] array = new int[8][8];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store values as in board use two dimensional array:

```
Square[][] chessboard=new Square[5][];
```

Now to assign new `Square` do:

```
chessboard[0][0]=new Square[];
```

To get existent square:

```
Square square = chessboard[3][5];
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what we have [arrays](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arrays.htm) for.
You can do

```
dataType[] arrayName = new dataType[arraySize];
```

to create an array of *dataType* and then assign values to it like this:

```
arrayName[0] = value1;
arrayName[1] = value2;
arrayName[2] = value3;
...
```

Or you can create an array and assign values to it inline like this:

```
dataType[] arrayName = {value0, value1, ..., valueN};
```

For your chess example, you should use a two-dimensional array.

Comment: please, add some data about arrays and links for learning center or something. It would be best answer!

Answer (score 0):

To assign each square on the chessboard to a variable,

```
int squares[][] = new int[8][8]; // 8 rows, 8 columns
                                 // squares[0][0] -- 1st row 1st column
                                 // squares[1][2] -- 2nd row 3rd column
```

**Note**: array variable index starts with 0.

or else you can use **collection API** in java [collection tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/)